# “This computer currently has no detected operating systems.”

Tags: partitioning, windows

I have got my new PC with Windows 10 installed on it. I am now trying to install Ubuntu which is the main OS I need, However since I have paid for Windows license, I do not want lose it!
Will this happen if I **Erase the disk and install Ubuntu**? If yes, how much space is enough to give to the Windows partition in order to just keep it.

Will I be able to change the partition size later after installation?

While I'm installing Ubuntu it says:

> This computer currently has no detected operating systems.

Why doesn't it detect the Windows? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the same kind of configuration having Elementary OS as primary and Windows 10 as secondary OS although my laptop came bundled with original Windows 10.
I use Windows just for some rare gaming and storing personal photos etc. I manage this with some 500GB but it can work even with 200GB and the remaining can be used for Linux. And yes, you can re-partition after installing OS.

I hope you are following these steps:

1. Freeing some space on the drive using Windows partiton tool.
2. Do not format this space i.e keep it unallocated.
3. Prepare your Ubuntu installation USB drive.
4. Insert and switch ON the PC. Let it boot into the Ubuntu installation.
5. While installing, just select the option "Something else".
6. There, select the unallocated space that you created using Windows 
   tool.
7. Let the installation proceed.

Comment: I agree with this answer, with one caveat: Resizing partitions by moving the start point can be time-consuming and risky. Thus, it's best to get the partition sizes right the first time, or at least lay things out so that you can resize in a way that does not involve moving the start point of any partition. (You could shrink the partition that comes first and create a new partition in the freed space, for instance. Another option is to use [LVM,](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm) but that's complex enough that it's probably not the best choice for a newbie.)

Comment: I completely agree with @RodSmith, one can re-partition but it is risky and time consuming. Thanks for that bit.